# Update two input fields in different components with redux

Tags: redux, reactjs, textinput

I am trying to get the following behavior in react using redux. I have two side by side components both have a `<input>` textfield that displays the same value. When I edit either of the field's, I want to dispatch an action and have redux store update the state of my app in both components

Exactly like asana app.

when I edit the field on left it updates the field on the right side as well 
[image]

and when i edit the field on right, It updates the text field on left as well
[image]

I can only get it working one way and not both ways. I am using the `value` prop of the `<input>` textfield and keeping a state variable to update the `<input>` textfield as described in
[react-docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).
I have state variable in one component and other one directly listens to the props.

I tried using the `defaultValue` prop if `<input>` textfield but it runs into other problems of not updating value when switching between different items

Comment: ref: https://www.sitepoint.com/video-controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components-in-react/
the difference in my case, my `<input>`'s are present in separate components (files/classes)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer this without seeing your code, but based on what you're saying it sounds like you are storing one input's value on state?

If I want a value to be linked to a global store, I wouldn't store it on state. I'd do something like this (a bit pseudocody but hopefully you get the idea!)

```
onChange: function (e) {
  this.props.dispatch(updateName(e.target.value));
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <input value={this.props.name} onChange={this.onChange} />
  );
}
```

The dispatch causes an update to the global store which then cascades that updated name value back down to the react component you are currently typing in, as well as the other input elsewhere that is populated by the same data.

Comment: That would not work as it becomes an un controlled component. Read this
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html
anyway, my problem arises when i have two of them in separate components and linked to the same value

Comment: It's still a controlled component as it is receiving a value as a prop and the value is being manipulated `onChange` higher-up the chain.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I have tried what you suggested but that still doesn't fix my problem, It only updates on the input fields.

Comment: It's hard to provide further insight into why it might not be working without seeing some code.